# How do I use an "array" as a Function variable?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4, pine-editor

We assume a generic function such as:
[a,b,c] = Function (float **Var1**, float Var2)

I want "**Var1**" to be *an array of type float*. How do I write the function?

Regards

(writing it as: array_new.float(Array, size) obviously does not work)...but you get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the array declaration/ type definition you have 2 options:

```
array<float> myArray = array.new_float(3,na)

float[] myArray2 = array.new_float(3,na)
```

The same applies to function definitions:

```
myFn(array<float> arr) =>
    array.get(arr, 0)

myFn2(float[] arr) =>
    array.get(arr, 0)
```